# Прошу помочь, не получается передавать выбранных(механизм/Цвет обивки/Материал) значении в url

Tags: javascript

```js
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function (){

        let url = window.location;
        let isChecked = false;

        // Вид дивана
        if (document.getElementById('vid_divan1').checked) {
            url = url + '/pryamoy-divan';
            isChecked = true;
        }
        if (document.getElementById('vid_divan2').checked) {
            url = url + '/uglovoy-divan';
            isChecked = true;
        }
        if (document.getElementById('vid_divan3').checked) {
            url = url + '/vid_divan3';
            isChecked = true;
        }
        if (document.getElementById('vid_divan4').checked) {
            url = url + '/vid_divan4';
            isChecked = true;
        }
        if (document.getElementById('vid_divan5').checked) {
            url = url + '/vid_divan5';
            isChecked = true;
        }
        if (document.getElementById('vid_divan6').checked) {
            url = url + '/vid_divan6';
            isChecked = true;
        }
        if (document.getElementById('vid_divan7').checked) {
            url = url + '/vid_divan7';
            isChecked = true;
        }
        
        // Цена
        if (isChecked) {
            url = url + '/tcena_' + document.getElementById('price1').value + '~' + document.getElementById('price2').value + '';
            location.href = url;
        }

        // Ширина
       if (isChecked) {
            url = url + '/width_' + document.getElementById('width1').value + '~' + document.getElementById('width2').value + '';
            location.href = url;
        }

        // Длина
        if (isChecked) {
            url = url + '/length_' + document.getElementById('length1').value + '~' + document.getElementById('length2').value + '';
            location.href = url;
        }
        
        // Механизм
        if (document.getElementById('mehanizm1').checked) {
            url = url + '/accordion';
            isChecked = true;
        }
        if (document.getElementById('mehanizm2').checked) {
            url = url + '/mehanizm2';
            isChecked = true;
        }
        if (document.getElementById('mehanizm3').checked) {
            url = url + '/mehanizm3';
            isChecked = true;
        }
        if (document.getElementById('mehanizm4').checked) {
            url = url + '/mehanizm4';
            isChecked = true;
        }
        if (document.getElementById('mehanizm5').checked) {
            url = url + '/mehanizm5';
            isChecked = true;
        }
        if (document.getElementById('mehanizm6').checked) {
            url = url + '/mehanizm6';
            isChecked = true;
        }
        if (document.getElementById('mehanizm7').checked) {
            url = url + '/mehanizm7';
            isChecked = true;
        }



        // Цвет обивки
        if (document.getElementById('color1').checked) {
            url = url + '/blue';
            isChecked = true;
        }
        if (document.getElementById('color2').checked) {
            url = url + '/green';
            isChecked = true;
        }
        if (document.getElementById('color3').checked) {
            url = url + '/color3';
            isChecked = true;
        }
        if (document.getElementById('color4').checked) {
            url = url + '/color4';
            isChecked = true;
        }
        if (document.getElementById('color5').checked) {
            url = url + '/color5';
            isChecked = true;
        }
        if (document.getElementById('color6').checked) {
            url = url + '/color6';
            isChecked = true;
        }



        // Материал
        if (document.getElementById('material1').checked) {
            url = url + '/velveteen';
            isChecked = true;
        }
        if (document.getElementById('material2').checked) {
            url = url + '/Jacquard';
            isChecked = true;
        }
        if (document.getElementById('material3').checked) {
            url = url + '/material3';
            isChecked = true;
        }
        if (document.getElementById('material4').checked) {
            url = url + '/material4';
            isChecked = true;
        }
        if (document.getElementById('material5').checked) {
            url = url + '/material5';
            isChecked = true;
        }
        if (document.getElementById('material6').checked) {
            url = url + '/material6';
            isChecked = true;
        }     

    })
```

```css
 body{font-family: Arial;}
    .flex{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        padding: 30px;
    }
    .flex span{
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    display: block;
    color: #bdbeca;
    }
    .flex2{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    .flex2 input:first-child{margin-left:0;}
    .flex2 input:last-child{margin-right:0;}
    .flex2 input{
    border: 1px solid #f3f3f3;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    outline: none;
    }
    .flex b{
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        font-style: 20px;
    }
    .flex .block{
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .flex > div{
        border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 10px;
        padding: 30px;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
    .center{
        text-align: center;
        padding: 30px;
    }
    #submit{background: #fcc314;
        color: white;
        border:0;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 15px 100px;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: bold;
        outline: none;
    }
    #clear{
    float: right;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 20px;
    color: #bdbeca;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"
  integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="flex">
    <div>
        <b>Вид дивана</b>
       <div class="block"> <input type="checkbox" id="vid_divan1"  value="link1"><label>Прямой диван</label></div>
       <div class="block"> <input type="checkbox" id="vid_divan2"  value="link2"><label>Угловой диван</label></div>
       <div class="block"> <input type="checkbox" id="vid_divan3"  value="link3"><label>Модульный диван</label></div>
       <div class="block"> <input type="checkbox" id="vid_divan4"  value="link4"><label>Детский диван</label></div>
        <div class="block"><input type="checkbox" id="vid_divan5"  value="link5"><label>Кухонный диван</label></div>
        <div class="block"><input type="checkbox" id="vid_divan6"  value="link6"><label>Кушетка</label></div>
        <div class="block"><input type="checkbox" id="vid_divan7"  value="link7"><label>Софа</label></div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <b>Цена</b>
        <div id="price-slider">
        </div>
        <div class="flex2">
            <input type="text" id="price1" name="price1" value="580">
            <input type="text" id="price2" name="price2" value="50000">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <b>Спальное место</b>

        <div class="block">
            <span>Ширина(см)</span>
            <div id="width-slider"></div>
            <div class="flex2">
                <input type="text" id="width1" value="30">
                <input type="text" id="width2" value="420">
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="block">
            <span>Длина(см)</span>
            <div id="length-slider"></div>
            <div class="flex2">
                <input type="text" id="length1" value="30">
                <input type="text" id="length2" value="420">
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div>
        <b>Механизм</b>
        <div class="block"><input type="checkbox" id="mehanizm1"  value="link1" checked><label>Аккордеон</label></div>
        <div class="block"><input type="checkbox" id="mehanizm2"  value="link2"><label>Выкатной</label></div>
        <div class="block"><input type="checkbox" id="mehanizm3"  value="link3"><label>Дельфин</label></div>
        <div class="block"><input type="checkbox" id="mehanizm4"  value="link4"><label>Еврокнижка</label></div>
        <div class="block"><input type="checkbox" id="mehanizm5"  value="link5"><label>Клик-клак</label></div>
       <div class="block"> <input type="checkbox" id="mehanizm6"  value="link6"><label>Книжка</label></div>
        <div class="block"><input type="checkbox" id="mehanizm7"  value="link7"><label>Пума</label></div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <b>Цвет обивки</b>
        <div class="block"><input type="checkbox" id="color1"  value="link1"><label>Голубой</label></div>
        <div class="block"><input type="checkbox" id="color2"  value="link2"><label>Зеленый</label></div>
        <div class="block"><input type="checkbox" id="color3"  value="link3"><label>Бежевый</label></div>
        <div class="block"><input type="checkbox" id="color4"  value="link4"><label>Коричневый</label></div>
        <div class="block"><input type="checkbox" id="color5"  value="link5"><label>Желтый</label></div>
        <div class="block"><input type="checkbox" id="color6"  value="link6"><label>Красный</label></div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <b>Материал</b>
        <div class="block"><input type="checkbox" id="material1"  value="link1"><label>Вельвет</label></div>
        <div class="block"><input type="checkbox" id="material2"  value="link2"><label>Жаккард</label></div>
        <div class="block"><input type="checkbox" id="material3"  value="link3"><label>Искусственная кожа</label></div>
        <div class="block"><input type="checkbox" id="material4"  value="link4"><label>Микровелюр</label></div>
        <div class="block"><input type="checkbox" id="material5"  value="link5"><label>Рогожка</label></div>
        <div class="block"><input type="checkbox" id="material6"  value="link6"><label>Текстиль</label></div>
    </div>

    </div>
<div class="block center">
    <button class="button" id="submit">Поиск</button>
    <button class="button" id="clear" onclick="uncheck();">Сбросить все</button>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Проверил, данный фрагмент успешно передал выбранные значения: ?editor_console=true/accordion/green/Jacquard

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Poul_WWJD/bz5esg1u/7/

Comment: работает. Подскажите, как добиться, чтоб при нажатии Сбросить все, также значение слайдера сбросились?

Comment: 1) Обернуть все поля ввода в форму; 2) кнопку (button) заменить на поле сброса; 3)убрать с бывшей кнопки обработчик ( uncheck();) который не нужен и только вызывает ошибку.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Poul_WWJD/bz5esg1u/11/

Comment: при нажатии Сбросить все, сбрасывается http://joxi.ru/52a1l8GiE5j9Y2 но слайдер не меняется http://joxi.ru/823OobNt9dvnk2